# VBA sending foreign characters to .net core 2 web api returns http code 400

Tags: vba, ms-word, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

net core 2 Web API that receives data from a VBA application. This works well until the data being sent is with foreign characters. what i get from vba is that it sends this

`UpdateTagForDocument?documentName=PDK415.doc&tagType=custom&newValue=DK-tag; Title-here 1; Mintetestćć;` 
(note that the actual domain has been removed for security purposes)

However i can see from Wireshark that the polish character 'ć' has been replaced with the this: \304\207 as shown here:

```
UpdateTagForDocument?documentName=PDK415.doc&tagType=custom&newValue=DK-tag;%20Title-here%201;%20test\304\207;
```

The following vba code sends the request:

```
Public Function request(requestName As String, thisRequestType As requestType, Optional postParameters As String = "", Optional format As ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json) As String
Dim xml
Dim requestType As String
requestType = GetRequestType(thisRequestType)
asd = url & requestName
Debug.Print asd
Set xml = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
xml.Open requestType, url & requestName, False
'xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1"
xml.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xml.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
If postParameters <> "" Then
    xml.send (postParameters)
Else
    xml.send
End If
pResponseText = xml.ResponseText
pStatusCode = xml.Status
pStatusText = xml.StatusText
If pStatusCode = "200" Then
    request = True
Else
    request = False
End If
End Function
```

Web API Action code:

```
    [Route("UpdateTagForDocument")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateTagForDocument (string documentName, string tagType, string newValue)
    {
        TagType convertedTagType;
        if (!Enum.TryParse<TagType>(tagType, true, out convertedTagType))
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Error converting to enum");
        }

        if(service.UpdateTag(documentName, convertedTagType, newValue))
            return Ok();

        return StatusCode(500);
    }
```

The Web API should just return a http code 200 and that's that.
However what i get is that it can't reach the server. Somehow MVC can't find the right Action in the controller and so just returns a http code 400 bad request.

However when i send the same request through Postman, with or withour the \304\207 code, there is no problem.

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: If using `Postman` to send requests show now problem that it is your `VBA` code that has issues. Converting polish characters to \xyz format is common in http world. It enables send none ASCII characters over the wire.

Comment: That was my conclusion as well, however i don't understand why the exact same request through Postman works, when VBA doesn't.